# Animate Progress bar Foreground Colour based on Range WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've got a progress bar that I need to animate based on a certain range, e.g:
0 - 30 - set progress bar's foreground to red
31 - 60 - set progress bar's foreground to orange
61 - 100 - set progress bar's foreground to green

This is what I currently have:

```
<ProgressBar Height="12" Canvas.Left="31" Canvas.Top="75" Width="24" Value="0">
            <ProgressBar.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent ="Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard >
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Value" From="0" To="{Binding Price, Mode=TwoWay}" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Orange" Duration="0:0:0.3"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ProgressBar.Triggers>
        </ProgressBar>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: When the `Value` is 65: Should the `Foreground` be RED-ORANGE-GREEN or only GREEN ?

Comment: You get callback whenever the progress value changes?

Comment: you can use IValueConverter

Comment: @NawedNabiZada it should only be green

Comment: @WPFUser do you have an example for me please?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada you found or still need a sample?

Comment: @WPFUser, I kind of thought this was solved with the answer Ignacio provided.

Comment: yes yes.. it is the solution.. @NawedNabiZada :)

Answer (score 1):

As WPFUser says you can use an `IValueConverter` that generates a color based on an int `enter code here`value. In this case you should return:

00 - 30: red 
31 - 60: orange 
61 - 100: green

Then use the value returned on the ProgressBar foregound